# PDO in PHP doesn´t work - no error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Here is my Code:

```
$query = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO veranstaltung_anfrage (id, name, bild, ort, datum, info, info_lang, beginn, eintritt, veranstalter, aname, atel, aemail, avorname, a plz, astrasse, url) VALUES (:a, :name, :bild, :ort, :datum, :info, :infolang, :beginn, :eintritt, :veranstalter, :a, :a, :a, :a, :a, :a, :a)");

$query->bindParam(':name', $name);
$query->bindParam(':bild', $bild);
$query->bindParam(':ort', $ort);
$query->bindParam(':datum', $datum);
$query->bindParam(':info', $info);
$query->bindParam(':infolang', $infolang);
$query->bindParam(':beginn', $beginn);
$query->bindParam(':eintritt', $eintritt);
$query->bindParam(':vertanstalter', $veranstalter);
$query->bindParam(':a', $a);

$a = "";
$name = $_POST['name']; 
$bild = 'bild.jpg';
$ort = $_POST['ort'];
$datum = $_POST['date1'];
$info = $_POST['info'];
$infolang = $_POST['infolang'];
$beginn = $_POST['time'];
$eintritt = $_POST['eintritt'];
$veranstalter = $_POST['veranstalter'];

$query->execute();
```

There is no error but also no database entry.. What´s wrong with my code?

Comment: yep!
execute is at the bottom and so it´s the right syntax!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to what @Niet Suggested you have to know that you cannot reuse the same name for the placeholder  like you did:

```
INSERT INTO veranstaltung_anfrage (....) VALUES (..:a, :a, :a, :a, :a, :a, :a)
```

You will need to give them unique names:

```
INSERT INTO veranstaltung_anfrage (....) VALUES (..:a1, :a2, :a3, :a4, :a5....)
```

then bind them one by one

Answer (score 1):

Looking at it, my three comments combine into quite an answer.

- You should probably define your parameters *before* you bind them. It's not strictly necessary (because you're using `bindParam` rather than `bindValue`), but it is a good idea because... well, trying to use something before it exists is absurd.
- `a plz` is not a valid column name. Either it's a type, or you need backticks around it, like `` `a plz` ``
- By default, PDO fails silently. I think that's stupid, but that's how it works. [Check the docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php) and enable Exception mode like this:

  ```
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  ```

Suddenly, errors!